# Commerce framework: How on earth do I offer recurring license subscriptions?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm new to the Commerce framework. My goal is to sell licenses to users (via [the commerce_license module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license)). Purchasing a license should grant the user a particular role for the duration of the license.

I need to offer the license in four different versions, described below. I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish this:

- License is good for one year; does not auto-renew ($99/year)
- License is good for one year; auto-renews each year (via [the commerce_recurring module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring)) ($89/year)
- License is good for one month; does not auto-renew ($9.99/month)
- License is good for one month; auto-renews each month ($8.99/month)

Can someone please explain to me how to implement this, in straightforward, step-by-step terms? What product types, product variation types, products, product attributes, order types, order item types, etc. do I need to create – and how should they be configured?

(My main problem is that I *really* don't understand the relationships between these various objects. I've read the docs. I've watched tutorial videos. I've scrutinized ERDs. I've spent hours experimenting in the Drupal dashboard. I've *tried* to read the code – but it's too convoluted for me. Maybe I'm dumb, but the Commerce framework is *extremely* confusing and counterintuitive.)

I would prefer to avoid any custom code – I just need the simplest solution that will satisfy the above requirements.

Any guidance ?

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, please explain how I could have posed this question better.

Comment: Have you read the README.txt from the module? There is a step by step walktrough "To create products that grant licenses that renew with a subscription:" How to configure them, depends on your needs. Note that the module is still incomplete, and is known for some limitations. That is probably why the maintainers only released an `alpha` release.

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) is in alpha.  That means it is not generally ready for production use.

Further, [Commerce Recurring](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring) is in beta, but the module page itself notes, as of January 2021:

> This module is not production ready! Expect pain.

Using these modules now will require writing custom code and debugging; there is no out-of-the-box easy solution at this time.

However, I needed a license solution today, so I decided to implement one in Commerce without using these modules.  Here's a rough sketch of how I did it.  **Note that I am renewing the subscriptions manually, which is prone to human error; the following flow only provides a UI for users to purchase and configure the period of their subscriptions.**

However, this example will hopefully give you an idea of the large amount of work involved in getting subscriptions set up.  It's not easy; if you want something simpler but still not easy, and in which the subscriptions actually recur properly, you could look at [Recurly](https://www.drupal.org/project/recurly) or other SaaS.

1. Add a role, **Premium user**.  Give this role the additional permissions that users will purchase.
2. Add a datetime field to the user account, **Subscription expire date**.  Add another list text field to the user account, **Subscription type**.
3. Add custom code to restrict permission for the **Subscription expire date** field to admins only.
4. Configure your store + checkout flow in Commerce.
5. Create a product type "My license."  Add product variations "One year autorenew," "One month," etc.
6. Add an EventSubscriber to Commerce to automatically set the user account field **Subscription expire date** when the purchase is complete.  Also, add a redirect to skip the cart because for individual users, having a cart makes no sense for licenses + I don't want users to purchase multiple subscriptions.

Skipping carts requires [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2810723) in `composer.json`:

```
    "drupal/commerce": {
        "allow order types to have no carts": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-10-05/2810723-130.patch"
    },
```

Even with all this effort, **you will still have to renew the subscriptions manually**.  I did this by adding a view for the admin of "expiring subscriptions" and then using the token stored in the user account by Commerce Stripe to make the recurring payment.

**Custom EventSubscriber**

Notes about this code: It includes an additional field, a list text field on the user account to let the users change between different subscription types.  This allows members to change from a monthly to an annual subscription, or vice versa.

It also assumes that "monthly" subscriptions are always 30 days.

First, **services.yml**:

```
services:
  mymodule_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\MYMODULE\EventSubscriber\MyModuleEventSubscriber
    arguments: ['@request_stack', '@logger.factory', '@datetime.time']
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

And here's the Event Subscriber from **mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/MyModuleEventSubscriber.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItemInterface;
use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEntityAddEvent;
use Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

/*
 * Event Subscriber MyModuleEventSubscriber.
 */
class MyModuleEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The request stack.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;

  /**
   * Logger factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory
   */
  protected $loggerFactory;

  /**
   * The time service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface
   */
  protected $time;

  /**
   * MyModuleEventSubscriber constructor.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request_stack
   *   The request stack.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory $logger_factory
   *   The logger factory.
   * @param \Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface $time
   *   The time service.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack, LoggerChannelFactory $logger_factory, TimeInterface $time) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
    // Specify that logs should be for this module.
    $this->loggerFactory = $logger_factory->get('mymodule');
    $this->time = $time;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [
      'commerce_order.place.post_transition' => 'postPlaceTransition',
      'mymodule_order.fulfill.post_transition' => 'onFulfillTransition',
      CartEvents::CART_ENTITY_ADD => 'tryJumpToCheckout',
      KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['checkRedirectIssued', -10],
    ];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Set fields and roles for user accounts that purchase subscriptions.
   */
  public function postPlaceTransition(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->getEntity();

    $order_type = $order->bundle();

    if ($order_type === 'MYORDERTYPE') {
      $price_monthly = 500;
      $price_annual = 5000;
      $subscription_monthly = 'monthly';
      $subscription_annual = 'annual';
      $customer = $order->getCustomer();

      $total_price_array = $order->get('total_price')->getValue();
      $total_price = intval(round($total_price_array[0]['number']));
      $drupal_now_timestamp = $this->time->getCurrentTime();
      $days_in_month = 30;
      $seconds_in_month = 60 * 60 * 24 * $days_in_month;
      $seconds_in_year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
      $subscription_end_timestamp = '';
      // If the user has already purchased, extend the subscription.
      if ($customer->hasRole('subscriber')) {
        $current_subscription_datetime = $customer->get('field_datetime_sub_end')->value;
        $current_subscription_datetime_object = \DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT, $current_subscription_datetime);
        $current_subscription_timestamp = $current_subscription_datetime_object->getTimestamp();
        if ($total_price === $price_monthly) {
          $subscription_end_timestamp = $current_subscription_timestamp + $seconds_in_month;
          $customer->set('field_list_text_sub_period', $subscription_monthly);
        }
        elseif ($total_price === $price_annual) {
          $subscription_end_timestamp = $current_subscription_timestamp + $seconds_in_year;
          $customer->set('field_list_text_sub_period', $subscription_annual);
        }
        else {
          $this->loggerFactory->error('Total price was outside the assigned range for subscription. (has subscriber role)');
        }
      }
      // Set the date for a new subscription.
      else {
        // The user is henceforth a subscriber.
        $customer->addRole('subscriber');

        if ($total_price === $price_monthly) {
          $subscription_end_timestamp = $drupal_now_timestamp + $seconds_in_month;
          $customer->set('field_list_text_sub_period', $subscription_monthly);
        }
        elseif ($total_price === $price_annual) {
          $subscription_end_timestamp = $drupal_now_timestamp + $seconds_in_year;
          $customer->set('field_list_text_sub_period', $subscription_annual);
        }
        else {
          $this->loggerFactory->notice('Total price was outside the assigned range for subscription. (no subscriber role)');
        }
      }
      $subscription_end_date_object = new \DateTime();
      $subscription_end_date_object->setTimezone(timezone_open('UTC'));
      $subscription_end_date_object->setTimestamp("$subscription_end_timestamp");
      $subscription_end_date_value = $subscription_end_date_object->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
      $customer->set('field_datetime_sub_end', $subscription_end_date_value);

      $customer->save();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tries to jump to checkout, skipping cart after adding certain items.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEntityAddEvent $event
   *   The add to cart event.
   */
  public function tryJumpToCheckout(CartEntityAddEvent $event) {
    // $purchased_entity = $event->getEntity();
    // if ($purchased_entity->bundle() === 'training_event') {
    $checkout_url = Url::fromRoute('commerce_checkout.form', [
      'commerce_order' => $event->getCart()->id(),
    ])->toString();
    $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->set('mymodule_jump_to_checkout_url', $checkout_url);
    // Clear status message "Product added to your cart".
    // @todo fix deprecated code.
    // drupal_get_messages('status');.
  }

  /**
   * Checks if a redirect url has been set.
   *
   * Redirects to the provided url if there is one.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent $event
   *   The response event.
   */
  public function checkRedirectIssued(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $redirect_url = $request->attributes->get('mymodule_jump_to_checkout_url');
    if (isset($redirect_url)) {
      $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirect_url));
    }
  }

}
```